# how to set Jenkins build section via Process Job DSL

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

We are trying to automate the job creation process for our projects. Via DSL script whatever project I am creating, in the build section, the Maven version is by default coming as 3.2 version. And for that that while building the project I am getting errors. If I am changing the Maven version to 3.5 then the builds are working fine.

Do we have a way to override the default maven config via DSL script or any way to set the maven version to the build section?

Please find below the groovy script used to create a new job

```
String gitRepository = 'ssh://git@xyz.com:1111/cegp/automation-test'
String buildBranch = 'develop'
String projectDisplayName = 'AUTOMATION-NEW'
String credentialIDGithub = '86b18703-xxx-yyyy'
println("JOB START :" + projectDisplayName)

String FolderName='Corporate/automation-jobs'

def file = readFileFromWorkspace('tags.txt')
def lines = file.readLines() 

 for (line in lines) { 
    println "${line}"
    noOfLines++
    def projectName = "${line}"
  
  // job definition
    mavenJob(FolderName + '/' + projectName) {
      label('maven3.5')
      logRotator {
            numToKeep(20)
        }

        description('GSC Automation Job:' + projectName)
        
        scm {
            git {
                branch(buildBranch)
                remote {
                    url (gitRepository)
                    credentials(credentialIDGithub)
                }
            }
        }
        
        triggers {
             cron('H * * * *')
        }
        wrappers {
            goals('clean verify -Dtags=' + projectName)
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We can use mavenInstallation('Maven 3.5') to set the Maven Version.

Please check below code

```
String gitRepository = 'ssh://git@xyz.com:8000/automation-test'
    String buildBranch = 'develop'
    String projectDisplayName = 'AUTOMATION-NEW'
    String credentialIDGithub = '86b18703-aaa-abbba-aaaa'
    println("JOB START :" + projectDisplayName)

String FolderName='Corporate/automation-jobs'

def file = readFileFromWorkspace('tags.txt')
 def lines = file.readLines() 

    println("FOLDER NAME :" + FolderName)
    def noOfLines = 0;
     for (line in lines) { 
        println "${line}"
        noOfLines++
        def projectName = "${line}"
      
      // job definition
        mavenJob(FolderName + '/' + projectName) {
          label('maven3.5')
          logRotator {
                numToKeep(20)
            }
    
          mavenInstallation('Maven 3.5')
            description('GSC Automation Job:' + projectName)
            
            scm {
                git {
                    branch(buildBranch)
                    remote {
                        url (gitRepository)
                        credentials(credentialIDGithub)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            triggers {
            
                 cron('H * * * *')
            }
          wrappers {
            preBuildCleanup()

            
    }
            goals('clean verify -Dtags=' + projectName)
                
        }
           
        }
      
}
```